# How do I load a file (in C) into a gloabally defined character array?

Tags: c, arrays, io

I really don't have a clue where to start on this one. I/O isn't exactly something I'm fluent in. I want to declare a global character array that will contain information from a text file.This array needs to be of size determined by the inut file. This is my only thought so far:

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    int N;
    char c_array[N];
    int main(){
        f = fopen("file.txt","r");
        File *infile;
        c_array[N] = fscanf(f) //Yeah I dont get how fscanf works either
        .........;
    }
```

The size will be determined by the size of the file (assuming it wont be a ridiculous length). The file (named file.txt) will contain something like:

```
    A 5 4
    4 C 3
    5 4 4
```

So in this case I would like c_array[N] = {A,5,4,4,c,3,5,4,4}, where N = 9.

Comment: what exactly is the end goal here

Comment: Just to get those values into the array, lets say so I can print them like "A544C3544"; (meaning ignore new lines and spaces).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

char *array;

int main()
{
    FILE* file;
    int sz,i=0;
    char c;
    file=fopen("file.txt","r");

    //get the file size in bytes
    fseek(file,0,SEEK_END);
    sz=ftell(file);
    //allocate the array based on the file size;
    array=(char*)malloc(sz);
    rewind(file);//rewind the file and start reading from the beginning

    while(c!=EOF)
    {
        c=getc(file);
        if(isalnum(c)) //if the character is number or letter save it in the array
        {
                array[i]=c;
                i++;
        }
    }
    fclose(file);
    for(int j=0; j<i; j++)
    {
        printf("%c",array[j]);
    }
    free(array);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Awesome thanks so much! That isalnum function is very handy, wish I would've know about it earlier, again thanks!